# Blend does not display localized string

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am writing a Windows 8 store app in xaml and c#, and am localizing strings using [the approach outlined in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx) .

It shows the string correctly when the app runs, but in Expression Blend design-time it always shows an empty string.

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="IDST_LOAD_TITLE" x:Name="pageTitle" Text=""
    Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="false" 
    Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
```

I've tried even getting rid of Text="" completely...

Any way to get this to work?

Thank you

Comment: I'm currently facing the same issue. Is there another approach for localizing that would be compatible with Blend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

create a class such as:

```
public class Strang
{
    public string          IDST_LOAD_TITLE
    { get { return Strings.IDST_LOAD_TITLE; } }

    public string          IDST_SAVE_TITLE
    { get { return Strings.IDST_SAVE_TITLE; } }
    ...
```

add it to your app.xaml:

```
<Application
    x:Class="MyApp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:myApp="using:MyApp"
    >

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
          <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
              <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
          </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

          <!-- Look here! -->
          <myApp:Strang x:Key="Strang" />

      </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and then in your page's xaml code, do something like so:

```
        <TextBlock 
            x:Name="m_titleStatic" 
            Text="{Binding IDST_LOAD_TITLE}" 
            DataContext="{StaticResource Strang}"
            />
```